# Area Density Heat Map QGIS

Tags: qgis, area, heat-map, density

I would like to make a heat map of "building density" based on the area of the building footprints (I have them in a geojson as polygons) in relation to their "non-building" surroundings based on fixed grid (or alternative). So in other words put a grid over the map 100x100m and in each grid sector look at the area relatioship between the building footprint and the surrounding footprint. The more building the denser.

How would I best go about this? Are there better ways to do area based heatmaps? I have calculated centroids for each building and made heat maps with that but I need something based on area not topology.

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to convert your polygons to binary raster and calculate the percent building cover within a moving (focal) window for each pixel. Here is how:

1. Convert the vector polygon building footprints to [binary raster](https://youtu.be/xtmj9vmb-JA)
   where building = 1, else 0.

   Raster > Conversion > [Rasterize (Vector
   to Raster)](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/vectorconversion.html#rasterize-vector-to-raster)

[image]

2. Run a moving window using some areal unit that is meaningful (e.g. 100m^2, acres, miles^2, etc.) with a mean statistic to calculate percent building cover per unit area.

   Processing Toolbox > GRASS >
   Raster > [r.neighbors](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.neighbors.html)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect!

Comment: This worked nicely. For anyone experiencing issues with step 1: make sure your vector layer has the same projection set as the crs in the project properties. I exported the layer with the right projection and reinserted it. This resolved any issues. (changing the projection settings in the layer did not).

Comment: Could someone please elaborate more on the r.neighbors settings? I'd like to solve the same problem but don't know the settings for a square kilometer for example.